# Web Crawling Google Scholar - Extracting part of HTML URL to be able crawl the next/previous page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I have been tasked with creating a search engine. I understand that I need to create an adaptable URL, I have found the source code that I need to use from the onclick attribute on the button however as this changes from page to page. I need my for loop to be able to read this each time the page changes to be able to update the new URL. I have provided an example of the URL I need to change in square brackets.

I have provided a picture with the highlighted source code I require and part of my unfinished code.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=9117984065169182779&after_author=c7lwAPTu__8J&astart=20

[https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=9117984065169182779&after_author=[NEW](https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=9117984065169182779&after_author=%5BNEW) AUTHOR/USER CODE]&astart=[NEW PAGE NUMBER]

```
def main_page(max_pages):
    page = 0
    newpage = soup.find_all('button', {'onclick': ''})
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=9117984065169182779&after_author='+str(newpage)'&astart='+str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'href': '/citations?hl=en&user='}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 10


main_page(1)
```

[Highlighted source code required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cu2H.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little regular expression and urllib.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib import parse

data = '''
<button onclick="window.location='/citations?view_op\x3dview_org\x26hl\x3den\x26org\x3d9117984065169182779\x26after_author\x3doHpYACHy__8J\x26astart\x3d30'">click me</button>
'''

PATTERN = re.compile(r"^window.location='(.+)'$")

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for button in soup.find_all('button'):
    location = PATTERN.match(button.attrs['onclick']).group(1)
    parseresult = parse.urlparse(location)
    d = parse.parse_qs(parseresult.query)
    print(d['after_author'][0])
    print(d['astart'][0])
```